# Exception in Memset

Tags: c++, mfc, memset

When try to do a memset it gives the following exception

"Unhandled exception at 0x1023af7d (PxSmartInterface.dll) in SendOutDllTestExe.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x40e3a80e."

My memset statement will look like this

memset(lpStatus, 0, csStatus.GetLength());

Comment: the information provided is vague.its difficult to figure out the problem with this information.please post your code if possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a C++ exception, it's an operating exception. Either you accessed memory that didn't exist or you corrupted a data structure and crashed its destructor. (I'm assuming you're trying to zero out a block before `delete`ing the structure it contains.)

In C++ you don't typically call `memset`. `std::fill` does the same thing (and typically calls through to `memset` if possible), but with type safety.

If you want to zero out blocks of memory before `free`ing them, you need a debugging library. There's no clean way to access an object's memory after its destructor has been called and before `free` is called. Debug malloc is probably a feature of your dev environment.

Edit: you might be able to access pre-`free` memory for objects, but not arrays, by overriding `delete`. But that is NOT an activity for a beginner/intermediate.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, `lpStatus` does not point to `csStatus.GetLength()` bytes of writable memory.  You need to examine the logic of how `lpStatus` is set.